# How can I increment date every 21 days in excel

Tags: excel

I want the date to be incremented in one field every 21 days continuously.
For Example,
A1 = 3/7/2021. I want it to change automatically after 21 days to be 24/7/2021 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()-DATE(2021,7,3),21)
```

Then format the outcome as you desire to show the date as you wish.

[image]

If you want to test it put any date you want in a cell then change both `TODAY()` to reference that cell.

[image]